# draw quantile lines and connect two violin plots

Tags: python, plotly

How do I draw quantile lines and connect two violin plots in plotly in Python?

For example, there is a library to do this in R (https://github.com/GRousselet/rogme). The library provided does not necessarily work when there are more than two groups.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is definitely no built-in method to do something this specific in Plotly. The best you can do is probably draw some lines, and consider writing a function or some loops if you need to do this for multiple groups of data for different quantile values.

Here is how I would get started. You can create a list or array to store all of the coordinates of the lines if you want to connect the same quantiles from the Grouped violin plots. I acknowledge what I have at the moment is hacky, as it relies on groups in Plotly having y-coordinates starting at 0 and increasing by 1. There might be a way to access the y-coordinates of grouped violin plots, I'd recommend looking into [the documentation](https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Violin.html).

Some more work will need to be done if you want to add text boxes to indicate the values of quantiles.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# generate some random data that is normally distributed
np.random.seed(42)
y1 = np.random.normal(0, 1, 1000) * 1.5 + 6
y2 = np.random.normal(0, 5, 1000) + 6

# group the data together and combine into one dataframe
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Group': 'Group1', 'Values': y1})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Group': 'Group2', 'Values': y2})
df_final = pd.concat([df1, df2])

fig = px.strip(df_final, x='Values', y='Group', color_discrete_sequence=['grey'])

quantiles_list = [0.05, 0.10, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 0.90, 0.95]

## this is a bit hacky and relies on y coordinates for groups starting from 0 and increasing by 1
y_diff = 0
## these store the coordinates in order to connect the quantile lines
lower_coordinates, upper_coordinates = [], []
for group_name in df_final.Group.unique():
    for quantile in quantiles_list:
        quantile_value = np.quantile(df_final[df_final['Group'] == group_name].Values, quantile)
        if group_name == 'Group1':
            lower_coordinates.append((quantile_value, 0.2+1*y_diff))
        if group_name == 'Group2':
            upper_coordinates.append((quantile_value, -0.2+1*y_diff))
        fig.add_shape(
                # Vertical Line for Group1
                dict(
                    type="line",
                    x0=quantile_value,
                    y0=-0.2+1*y_diff,
                    x1=quantile_value,
                    y1=0.2+1*y_diff,
                    line=dict(
                        color="black",
                        width=4
                    )
                ),
        )
    y_diff += 1

## draw connecting lines
for idx in range(len(upper_coordinates)):
    fig.add_shape(
            dict(
                type="line",
                x0=lower_coordinates[idx][0],
                y0=lower_coordinates[idx][1],
                x1=upper_coordinates[idx][0],
                y1=upper_coordinates[idx][1],
                line=dict(
                    color="chocolate",
                    width=4
                    )
                ),
    )
fig.show()
```

[image]